# How to put overlay text using d3.js (javascript) in html

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a graph created in javascript (its just a d3.js graph). I thought it would be cool to have a title overlying the graph in a webpage. I understand html layouts and that overlying html can't be done this way. Is there a way I don't understand or am I going to have to try to render text on the graph as part of the javascript?

Comment: If you using json file to read your data you could put your text in it and put overlay text easily. If you create your graph with path tag you can use this:   `<textPath
            xlink:href="#PATH_ID"
            startOffset="50%">Some text</textPath>`

Comment: whats stopping you from overlaying html text on top of your graph ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy. How would I do that. The svg is created from javascript. Do you mean creating the html in the javascript?

Comment: whichever you want, you can either set the position in the html or set the html via javascript which will edit the position. All you need is css positioning, so if you want to explicitly set the position you set the position of your text in you css to fixed